# Lost /home mount, how to create the default config files for the users which are already present?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, recovery

I have lost access to `/home`.
Here is the message I get when I log in:

```
-bash: /home/chinde/.bash_profile: Stale file handle
```

I want to create the **default** files `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` for the users.

How to do that?

I tried doing this:

```
xew@server:/local/xew/backup$ mkhomedir_helper xew
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The question lacks details of the current state of the home directory (directories). `man 8 mkhomedir_helper` says

> The helper never touches home directories if they already exist.

so maybe this is why the tool didn't do anything. The manual also mentions `/etc/skel`. This is the default directory where files would be copied from. The directory is also mentioned in `man 8 useradd` and in (default) comments in `/etc/default/useradd`. Additionally you can study fragments of `man 8 adduser` where it mentions `SKEL`.

The conclusion is you should be able to find "skeletal" user files in a directory specified by the `SKEL=` line (if not commented out) of `/etc/default/useradd` or in the **default location which is `/etc/skel/`**.

**You can copy these files by hand, simply with `cp`.** Notes:

- `/etc/skel` corresponds to a home directory; so if you want to copy something from `/etc/skel/.config/`, the target directory should also be `.config/` in the home directory.
- To restore *other users'* default files you need access to their home directories; **don't forget to change the ownership**, so the new files are theirs. Any user should be able to copy from `skel` and if they do it on their own then the new files will naturally be owned by them; therefore `sudo -u another_user cp -ai …` is a decent option.